# SQL SELECT from two tables to set a variable in the select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

`alerts {id, title, description}`

`read_alerts {alert_id}`

i want to execute a sql that returns the following:

`alerts {id, title, description, is_read}`

The `is_read` needs to be `1` or `0`. 1 if the id is set in `read_alerts`, 0 otherwise.

What would be the best approach to achieve this in one sql query?

I am using Sqlite

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: a solution in which this can be achieved by using only one query. I dont need to consider execution time or something like this

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this uses a subquery in the `select` clause:

```
select a.*
       (case when exists (select 1 from read_alerts ra where ra.alert_id = a.id)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as is_read
from alerts a;
```

The key reason for using a subquery in the `select` clause is because you don't specify whether `read_alerts` can have multiple rows.  This version of the query  guarantees one row per alert, regardless of the contents of `read_alerts`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done either with an outer join:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.title,
       a.description,
       ra.id IS NOT NULL AS is_read
FROM alerts AS a
LEFT JOIN read_alerts AS ra on a.id = ra.alert_id;
```

or with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id,
       title,
       description,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM read_alerts
               WHERE alert_id = alerts.id
              ) AS is_read
FROM alerts;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, title, description, (CASE WHEN read_alert is not null THEN 1 else 0) as is_read
FROM alerts, read_alerts;
```